# How do I convert 2019-06-30 00:00:00.000 string variable to a date in SPSS?

Tags: datetime, syntax, spss

I have this string variable (2019-06-30 00:00:00.000) in a .csv file and upon import to SPSS I try to change it to a date variable, which isn't working. I have tried the data and time wizard and there isn't an option for this format so it won't work either. Does anyone have syntax they could share with me to make this conversion? TIA!

I have done google searches for the answer but haven't had any luck yet.

Answer (score 0):

If all of your strings follow that format, you should be able to convert your string variable (`var`) into a date using the code below.

```
COMPUTE datevar=NUMBER(var, YMDHMS23.3) .
FORMATS datevar (YMDHMS23.3) .
```

*Source: IBM docs*

- https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/converting-non-date-formatted-variables-date-format-spss
- https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spss-statistics/27.0.0?topic=formats-date-time

> *w* indicates the total number of columns and *d* indicates the number of decimal places for fractional seconds
>
> | General form | Format type |
> | --- | --- |
> | yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.s | YMDHMSw.d |